# Cast to a type inside a LINQ To Entity Query

Tags: c#, linq, casting

I have this LINQ query

```
var Cities= (from city in AllCities
    where (city.NumberOfCitizens > 1000)
    select new
    {
        Mayor= (from mayor in AllMayors where mayor.CityKey == city.Key select mayor),
        Name = city.Name,
        Country = city.Country,
        Key = city.Key
        }).ToList();
```

I select the Mayor, name, Country and key from the cities that I have > 1000 citizen.

`Mayor` is a class has 2 properties `String FirstName` and `String LastName`

Now I want to do another query on the `Cities` (which is the result of the first query) that extract the `FirstName` and `LastName` of the mayor in the Cities that has a key > 20

```
var Result= (from city in Cities
    where (city.Key> 20)
    select new
    {
        MayorFirstName = city.Mayor.FirstName,
        MayorLastName = city.Mayor.LastName,
        City = city.Name
        }).ToList();
```

The Problem is that I get a build error that city.Mayor does not contain a definition of `FirstName` and `LastName`

I tried to cast it to the Mayor type inside the query:

```
Mayor= (Mayor)(from mayor in AllMayors where mayor.CityKey == city.Key select mayor),
.......
```

The application build and start normally, but i get a runtime error that I cannot Cast to a type inside a LINQ query.

How can I solve this problem? Is there a way to cast inside the query or is there other solution.

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of this part of your query is NOT a single `Mayor` object, but `IEnumerable<Mayor>`

```
Mayor = (from mayor in AllMayors where mayor.CityKey == city.Key select mayor)
```

Change this line to:

```
Mayor= (from mayor in AllMayors where mayor.CityKey == city.Key select mayor).FirstOrDefault()
```

Then the Mayor property will be a single `Mayor` instance.

Note that using `FirstOrDefault` will return *null* if no mayor is found, while `First()` will throw an exception is no mayor is found.  The choice between these depends on your situation.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of assigning an `IEnumerable<Mayor>` to Mayor, you want to select a single item. Use Enumerable.First() with a predicate to do that:

```
Mayor = AllMayors.FirstOrDefault(mayor => mayor.CityKey == city.Key)
```

An in your example:

```
var Cities= (from city in AllCities
             where (city.NumberOfCitizens > 1000)
             select new
             {
               Mayor= AllMayors.FirstOrDefault(mayor => mayor.CityKey == city.Key),
               Name = city.Name,
               Country = city.Country,
               Key = city.Key
             }).ToList();
```